# Parse.com : ArrayList of pointer has changed

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

I'm developing an Android app.
Since few times I guess, when I save an arraylist of ParseUser pointer, the format seems to be changed. At the moment, When I check on the web console I have :

```
[{"authData":{"facebook":{"access_token":"EAAF9a5Q2GmABACsjGJaGZApLjQJ9lUOEJCVlwtjOmeMqqpFIzpipDLJKmK4XQTZBmAnCvB8WMxRbFWOeiM8ah3PZCZC7uEVxn2zxR15SRiaxSXSJYuRkdToJEMxskrJdZCcOa5jZC83LsiJnMpdXeApvPe8aF2snHyLxkXnnmnCJooYo2E10OUP5ZAEP4DIKtoRMd0zP1iTpBHiObMLtBeG","expiration_date":"2016-08-28T18:05:53.324Z","id":"10208295291119111"}},"createdAt":"2016-05-26T19:43:51.350Z","displayName":"vok","email":"vokvince@yahoo.fr","facebook":"10208295291119111","firstName":"Vincent","hasFinishPath":true,"lastName":"Hurbourque","name":"Vincent Hurbourque","objectId":"M1si6wZe4Y","tags":"vincent hurbourque vok","updatedAt":"2016-06-29T18:05:54.542Z","username":"bNKiRQseDwFXetuDy6XkQQclj"}]
```

[image]

It seems Parse copy all the data but it's not a pointer, so it's impossible searching a value inside this field.

Do you have this issue too?

Thx !

Comment: can you please paste your client code (Android) it's very difficult to understand your logic.

Comment: @RanHassid done :)

Comment: Please stop posting answers to your questions unless they are actually answers. You have to [edit] the question!

Comment: strange.. can you try to add another array of pointer of different type (not ParseUser but some other type) into the column and see the results?

Answer (score 0):

parse-server is using MongoDB behind the scenes. MongoDB is a document storage database which stores JSON's. so each time that you save an object to MongoDB you actually save a JSON document (object with key-value paris inside it). since MongoDB is NoSQL database (and not rational DB like MYSQL for example) it saved his relationship to other collections in a JSON format and this is exactly what you see in parse dashboard. I understand that it's hard to search there, i guess this is because how parse-dashboard is presenting the data of pointers but this is how it should work. 
I had the same situation as you are so what i did is i created a web app report which fetch the data that i want from parse.com (using Parse JS SDK) and display it in a table. each row in the table contains a link that present the data of the list (in your case **friends**) which exist under this row.

another option is to use one of the MongoDB admin UI's which provide data-viewing for  your MongoDB

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/